# Calculate height of rectangle in perspective

Tags: geometry

How can one calculate the height of a rectangle where the bottom part is unknown.
The rectangle is in perspective, I know the top part and sides. However not the bottom.

**Extra info:** it's a picture taken of a paper, due to the angle of the camera the object is in perspective, top part being the furthest away and bottom part outside of the camera closest to you.

---

**Situation like this:**
I know the green intersections, therefore the width in between and both sides (not the length obvious).
[image]

---

Below is how I think it should be done, but it's not precise so I'm looking for people to help me determine if I'm doing something wrong or can improve it.

[image]

```
#Paper size:
Pw=21.02cm
Ph=29,73cm

Calibration constant, number of pixels per cm at 50cm distance:
k = ### pixels/cm = (observed pixels calibrated)/Pw
kdist = 50cm

Q = k * Pw pixels width on the observed paper

Distance to top:
dtop = kdist*Q/Px

Px is the top width in pixels

We define a new point for measurement of the width, and define pixels to be perfect squares.
Py = 0.1 * Px (10% down)

New width for the new point, Py: is being manually measured for now.
Px2 calculated at Py.

Distance to Px2:
d2 = kdist*Q/Px2

Calculate height between top and Py:
h = sqrt(sqr(0.1*Pw)+sqr(dtop-d2))

Ratio between 0.1*Pw and full paper length:
r = Ph/h

Bottom line will be:
Y = r*Py
```

Comment: What height do you mean? A rectangle is two dimensional, and lacks the dimension of height. A rectangle consists of two sets of equal sides, whose pairings parallel and opposite of each other. Perhaps I'm missing something here?

Comment: Are you attempting to calculate the side based on its perspective, or is it its absolute length? Specify, if you would.

Comment: Sorry maybe I wasn't specific. I'm trying to calculate the length from the top (green intersections) to the bottom (blue intersections).

Comment: Is it simply a rectangle, whose side lengths you are given three of, and need to find the remaining side's length? If so, please provide the lengths for each side of which you are aware.

Comment: I'm only aware of the top width, that is the length between left green to right green intersection. That's all. Then I know the sides too, but not the length of them. And then I'm trying to find where the bottom section is, which is outside the camera view.

Comment: and this is a common rectangle, whose bottom side's, opposite the top side (whose length you know), length you wish to know? Is there anything else special about this?

Comment: No it's a very common rectangle, but it's in perspective, which is making everything harder. It's common because it's just a sheet of A4 paper taken with a camera from your point of view.

Comment: What does the perspective have at all to do with its dimensions? If I took a piece of 4x4in paper and put it within a desk and mailed it to Malaysia, the paper would still maintain the same dimensions.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14313/discussion-between-alx-and-jafu)

Comment: Of course the paper will look bigger when it's closer to you. I don't get your metaphor, all I mean is that the top length will be shorter than the bottom length because it's further away from your eyes (camera). If it was all straight I could simply measure the length of the top and get the height by the ratio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with using 
"Calibration constant, number of pixels per cm at 50cm distance"
is that not all of the scene is at 50cm depth or distance from the camera.

I think you need to remove the perspective correction first like in this example...
http://opencv-code.com/tutorials/automatic-perspective-correction-for-quadrilateral-objects/

[image: Perspective remapping]

Your green points would be the red and green ones in this example. Now obviously you want your blue points to be the white and blue in this example, which you don't have because they are outside the image. But if you work out where the left and right edges will coincide with the bottom edge of the image (the last row) you can still perform the perspective correction.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/9T1iBIY.jpg]

Now the correction is removed you can map pixels to cm and estimate where the bottom edge will appear.

Comment: This was the best idea and accepted answer, although I ended up going with feature matching similar to this: http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_feature_homography/py_feature_homography.html